# Arredondamento de casas decimais float python

Tags: python, tkinter, float

Olá, eu estou começando agora aprender programação e fiz uma calculadora que faz o calculo da formula Bhaskara e ela possui interface, utilizei o Tkinter.

Minha duvida é a seguinte eu queria que o numero que aparece em uma formula matemática tivesse 4 ou 5 casas decimais. Eu li em alguns fóruns sobre utilizar o `round` ou `decimal`, e consegui mas não para meu código, pois o valor que quero arrendondar está em variável **rd**, em **rd** tem uma formula da raiz de delta, por exemplo, e não consegui uma forma que ele arrendondasse. E esse resultado **'rd'** esta dentro será mostrado em uma **label**, e acredito que esse seja o ponto mais difícil se fosse utilizar somente o `print` daria certo mas está em uma **label**. 
Vou deixar o código e se tiverem alguma dica para encurtar o código eu agradeço, como faço para que na **label** saia com um numero de casas decimais que eu quero?

## python3

```py
def cof_a():
    a=float(eda.get())
    b=float(edb.get())
    c=float(edc.get())
    cof_z=(b**2-4*a*c)

    lb_delta['text']=cof_z


def raiz_d():
    a=float(eda.get())
    b=float(edb.get())
    c=float(edc.get())
    rd=((b**2-4*a*c)**0.5)

    lb_rdelta['text']=rd


def x1():#funçao para raiz de x1
    a=float(eda.get())
    b=float(edb.get())
    c=float(edc.get())
    rx1=(-b+((b**2-4*a*c)**0.5))/(2*a)

    lb_x1['text']=rx1


def x2():#funçao para raiz de x2
    a=float(eda.get())
    b=float(edb.get())
    c=float(edc.get())
    rx2=(-b-((b**2-4*a*c)**0.5))/(2*a)

    lb_x2['text']=rx2


#######################LABELS DE A,B,C####################################
lba=Label(janela , text='Digite o valor do coeficiente de "a" em ax² ', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lba.place(x=30, y=40)
eda=Entry(janela, bg='white', fg='black', font='verdana')
eda.place(x=420, y=40)

lbb=Label(janela , text='Digite o valor do coeficiente de "b" em bx   ', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lbb.place(x=30, y=80)
edb=Entry(janela, bg='white', fg='black', font='verdana')
edb.place(x=420, y=80)

lbc=Label(janela , text='Digite o valor do coeficiente de "c" em c     ', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lbc.place(x=30, y=120)
edc=Entry(janela, bg='white', fg='black', font='verdana')
edc.place(x=420, y=120)
##################


###############LABEL VALOR DE DELTA##################################
lb_delta=Label(janela, bg='#6B8E23', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_delta.place(x=380, y=240)

lbcof=Label(janela , text='O Delta ou Binômio discriminante é =', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lbcof.place(x=30, y=240)

#########################LABEL RAIZ DE DELTA##############################
lb_rdelta=Label(janela, bg='#6B8E23', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_rdelta.place(x=380, y=280)

lb_raizdelta=Label(janela , text='O valor da raiz quadrada do delta é =', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_raizdelta.place(x=30, y=280)

#########################LABELS X1 E X2############################
lb_x1=Label(janela , text='A raiz x1 é ', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_x1.place(x=60, y=360)

lb_x1=Label(janela, bg='#6B8E23', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_x1.place(x=60, y=400)


lb_x2=Label(janela , text='A raiz x2 é ', bg='#006400', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_x2.place(x=360, y=360)

lb_x2=Label(janela, bg='#6B8E23', fg='white', font='verdana')
lb_x2.place(x=360, y=400)
###############################################################################
```

Comment: Talvez utilizando a função round?

Answer (score 0):

A parte do teu código, tenta:

```
def raiz_d():
    a=float(eda.get())
    b=float(edb.get())
    c=float(edc.get())
    rd=((b**2-4*a*c)**0.5)
    rd = round(rd,2)
    lb_rdelta['text']=rd
```

Em um teste direto (passando os valores manualmente), o resultado foi:

```
a 10
b 20
c 3
16.73
```

E sem o `round()` ficaria `16.73320053068151`